# Animating Hover effect not working inside of ul > li

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

so I'm trying to re-create this really [cool hover effect seen here](http://www.uniqlo.com/us/mens-clothing), when you rollover the big sales images on the left.

Chris Coyier then created a [super detailed tutorial here.](http://css-tricks.com/uniqlo-stripe-hovers/)
Basically on rollover, this cool diagonal stripped background starts animating behind your div/box/image.

Everything works except when I wrap the div's inside of a list (ul li). Once I do that my code stops working :( is there a way around that? Or what newbie mistake am I making?

**Here is my codepen:**
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/hpzqD

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>

    <div class="thumb">
      <div class="thumb-hover"></div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3k3d1g3K34470d2v2K3O/50d942d85384a.jpeg"/>
        </a>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
}

.thumb {
  width: 376px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.thumb > img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.thumb:hover .product-hover, .thumb:active .product-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.thumb-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 25%, transparent 25%,   transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  animation: barberpole 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes barberpole {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }

  to {
    background-position: 60px 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit I'm starting to get my codepen fork to work with the ul > li http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/nbCpw now gotta figure out what's going on in my main project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a small typo in your example.  .product-hover should become .thumb-hover

Also, you'll want your css to be .thumb > a{ display: block; position: relative; }  Without that the bar animation will be on top of your image.

In your codepen change the scss to the following:

```
> a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
&:hover, &:active {
 .thumb-hover {
   opacity: 1; 
 }
```

}

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ACewa

Comment: Hi Smurfarita, I implemented the exact code from:http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/nbCpw to my site here:http://leongaban.com/ However not seeing the hover effect for some reason, may post a new stack question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to affect the `<img>` in your code snippet, this isn't going to work:

```
.thumb > img { ... }
```

That (specifically the `>`) means *"apply the following rule to `<img>` elements that are direct descendents (children) of any element with class `.thumb`."*  But per your markup, that's not the case.  Try just removing the `>` in that CSS rule definition.

Comment: Actually the effect is on the .thumb-hover div not the image, also Chris has the samething for .product http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/AzdcK